# RuntimeWarning when using EllipticEnvelope

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use Elliptic Envelope to detect outliers in my data. However after scaling I get many Runtime warnings that prevent me from having the predictions I'm looking for.

```py
C:\HOMEWARE\Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\covariance\robust_covariance.py:677: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  self.dist_ /= correction
C:\HOMEWARE\Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\covariance\robust_covariance.py:716: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  mask = self.dist_ < chi2(n_features).isf(0.025)
C:\HOMEWARE\Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\covariance\robust_covariance.py:720: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
  location_reweighted = data[mask].mean(0)
C:\HOMEWARE\Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:78: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  ret, rcount, out=ret, casting='unsafe', subok=False)
C:\HOMEWARE\Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:392: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
  avg = a.mean(axis)
C:\HOMEWARE\Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\covariance\empirical_covariance_.py:81: RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice
  covariance = np.cov(X.T, bias=1)
C:\HOMEWARE\Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:2451: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  c *= np.true_divide(1, fact)
C:\HOMEWARE\Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:2451: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
```

```py
  team  Family       date      Amount  scaled_amount
0  S  Engineering 2018-01-05   -0.02      -1.000000
1  S  Engineering 2018-02-06   -0.01      -0.333333
2  S  Engineering 2018-03-06    0.00       0.333333
3  S  Engineering 2018-04-06    0.00       0.333333
4  S  Engineering 2018-05-07    0.00       0.333333
5  S  Engineering 2018-06-06    0.00       0.333333
6  S  Engineering 2018-07-05    0.00       0.333333
7  S  Engineering 2018-08-06    0.00       0.333333
8  S  Engineering 2018-09-06    0.00       0.333333
9  S  Engineering 2018-10-04    0.01       1.000000
```

The code I used for prediction is the following:

```py
scaled_amount_reshaped = key.scaled_amount.values.reshape(-1, 1)
model = EllipticEnvelope(contamination=0.18)
model.fit(abs(scaled_amount_reshaped))
prediction = model.predict(abs(scaled_amount_reshaped))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
model = EllipticEnvelope(contamination=0.18 , support_fraction=0.7)
```

Or check this way:
If you have chunks, try to use DASK and mix to your code as:
[Tensorflow-DASK](https://github.com/Hassankashi/Tensorflow-DASK/blob/master/Tensorflow-DASK.py)

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.covariance import EllipticEnvelope
true_cov = np.array(your matrix)
X = np.random.RandomState(0).multivariate_normal(mean=[0, 0],cov=true_cov,size=500)

model = EllipticEnvelope(random_state=0).fit(X)
# predict returns 1 for an inlier and -1 for an outlier
model.predict(X`) #abs(scaled_amount_reshaped)
```

Comment: The first one gives same results. The second gives results only to a fraction of the data and sometimes doesn't give any at all

Comment: @MohamedBelahcen sometimes does not give warning? Could you please let me know when there are warnings, what are they? The same one that you posted?

Comment: Oh let me explain? I have a dataset that I divided into chunks like the df above. For every chunk I perform EllipticEnvelope. So sometimes i get warnings for a chunk and sometimes I don't. Above is an example of a chunk where I do get warnings and thus don't get any predictions. For the majority I get quite good results but not for some important chunks

Comment: I suspect that this is a common problem with univariate data since EllipticEnvelope is mostly for multivariate

Comment: @MohamedBelahcen Please look at X = np.random.RandomState(0).multivariate_normal(mean=[0, 0],cov=true_cov,size=500)
and change size according to your chunk. Or iterate inside this size with your chunk. Let me know if it can help.

Comment: @MohamedBelahcen I meant to change your size to more and see if the problem exists for example size=1000